# Unix sort: sort by specific character following another character

Tags: sorting, unix

I have a file that contains information in the following form:

```
"dog/3/cat/6/fish/2/78/90"
```

(we'll not worry about the last two values here)

Is it possible to sort the contents of the file by the numeric value after the odd numbered slashes with the unix `sort` command?

For instance, the output might look like this:

```
dog/4/house/3/frog/89/100
dog/3/mouse/2/chicken/12/68/80
dog/2/cat/5/bird/12/77/90
```

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. You want to sort by "/" but only for odd numbered slashes?

Comment: @user3589054 I want to sort it by the number that follows the slash

Comment: your question would benefit from a [mcve]. Otherwise this is a bit unclear.

Comment: More than a "bit" unclear, actually.

Comment: Just a bad way of asking the question. The question maybe a good one :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should give you what you want, I think:

`sort -t/  -k2,2nr -k4,4nr -k6,6nr`

Comment: I think you want `sort -t/ -k2,2n -k4,4n`  Using `-k2,4` will make field 3 relevant.